# Yii Gridview Search Value of Displayed Text

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I am currently using Yii to create a basic gridview.  What I have done is changed the displayed text inside the gridview and am trying to figure out how to get the search function to be able to search through the text that is displayed.   The problem is that it is still searching the value that is stored.

My gridview piece that i am trying to search:

```
array(
                'name'=>'enabled',
                'value'=>'convertEnabled($data->enabled)',
                'type'  => 'raw',
            ),
```

My function to change the value is simple:

```
function convertEnabled($value)
    {
        if($value == '1')
        {
            $returnedVar = 'Enabled';
        }
        else
        {
            $returnedVar = 'Disabled';
        }
        return $returnedVar;
    }
```

What I need my gridview to do is search for enabled/disabled and not 1 or 0.

The search for it right now looks like `$criteria->compare('enabled',$this->enabled);`

How do I get it to search the displayed text and not the value of the item?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to search by `enabled` or `disabled` instead of `0` or `1` which is stored in your database, right ?

To do that you can simply add this your model `search`, something like:

```
public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        if($this->enabled != "") {
            if($this->enabled == "enabled") {
                $criteria->compare('enabled', 1);
            } elseif($this->enabled == "disabled") {
                $criteria->compare('enabled', 0);
            } else {
                $criteria->compare('enabled',$this->enabled, true);
            }
        }

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

You will be getting the user entered value in `$this->enabled` you can compare it to check if they have searched for `enabled` or `disabled` and add the `compare` attribute or `addCondition` with its corresponding value from the database. Hope that helps :)